# Google Apps Script/Javascript search and replace with regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I know there are many similar questions and answers out there but I have had no luck.

I simply want to run a regex on a Google Doc and have it replace what it finds with Uppercase.          I have a working regular expression, and a simple string replace works, but I can't get a regex of any kind to work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
function searchAndReplace() {
var bodyElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var regExp = new RegExp(/[\n][\n]([^\n]+)[\n][^\n|\s]/gim);
bodyElement.replaceText(regExp, '$1'.toUpperCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the [replaceText documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String)), it expects a `string` on both parameters. The first one will automatically generate a `RegExp` for you. Therefore you can use a regular expression, but due to this syntax limitation, you can not pass `RegExp` flags to it (in your example the `gim`).

Also, since the second parameter also only accepts a string, you can not inform a function, which is what you'd need to make a proper `toUpperCase` (which is wrong in your example even if using javascript built-in [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function).

And from tests I just made, replacement string patterns using "$&" or "$#" don't work either.

So, to achieve what you're looking for you'll have to implement this search-and-replace yourself (possibly using [findText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String)) to help on the "search" part).

Comment: Thanks!  Now I see why it doesn't work.  Bummer tho! :(

Comment: You're welcome. And since you're new to StackOverflow, please remember to accept an answer when you feel you got a good one. It's a check mark under the voting arrows (another nice SO feature).

Comment: Thanks.  Technically you answered my question why my function doesn't work.  But I still don't have a solution to finding and replacing the strings I'm interested in in google apps script.  Should I open another question for that?

Comment: Yes, I answered you (since the bottom line question was "What am I doing wrong?"). And I even explained you how to solve it (by coding it yourself, using `findText` and then built-in string `replace`). There's no easy way. Just to clarify, asking for ready programs/functions is not a programming doubt, which is StackOverflow's scope. If you attempt to code it yourself and get stuck, then you should open a new question.