# google doc script, attributes (bold, italics, underline) not shown in log

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps

i want to create a script to capitalize sentences in a google doc, but without changing existing attributes in certain words. for example, in a google doc, there would be several paragraphs, with each paragraph having several sentences. in such google doc, there would be hyperlinks, words in boldface, words in italics, words with underline, etc. i want all of these attributes to stay intact; the script should only capitalize the sentences, without removing the existing attributes for these words.

below is a code in which i tried to print out the attributes:

```
function cap12b() {

  // define function "replacement" to change the matched pattern to uppercase
  function replacement(match) { return match.toUpperCase(); }

  // define regex "period, followed by zero or any number 
  // of blank spaces, followed by any lowercase character"
  var regex1 = "(^|\.)(\s*)[a-z]";
  var regex2 = /(^|\.)(\s*)[a-z]/;
  Logger.log('regex1 -> %s, regex2 -> %s', regex1, regex2);

  // var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().editAsText();
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  Logger.log('doc -> %s', doc);
  Logger.log('body -> %s', body);
  var atBody = body.getAttributes();
  Logger.log('atBody -> %s', atBody);

  // get body to edit as text
  // var body = body.editAsText();
  var idBody = body.editAsText().getTextAttributeIndices();
  Logger.log("idBody -> %s", idBody);

  // get element text matching pattern "regex"
  var foundElement = body.findText(regex1);
  Logger.log('foundElement -> %s', foundElement);

  // get attributes of foundElement
  var atFE = foundElement.getElement().getAttributes();
  Logger.log("atFE -> %s", atFE);

  while (foundElement != null) {

    var foundText = foundElement.getElement();

    // get attributes of foundText
    // var atFT = foundText.getAttributes();
    // Logger.log("atFT -> %s", atFT);

    // capitalize the character after the period   
    var str1 = foundText.getText();
    var str2 = str1.replace(regex2, replacement);
    foundText.setText(str2); // running, but removed attribute

    // Find the next match
    foundElement = body.findText(regex1, foundElement);

  }

  // try to set attributes in variable "atBody" to body 
  var body = body.setAttributes(atBody);
  Logger.log("body -> %s", body);
  return body;

}
```

the document contained the following paragraph, with a word in boldface, a word in italics, a word in underline:

> capitalize sentences.  this is one example with ONE blank space after
>   the period.  here is another example with TWO blank spaces after the
>   period.          this is yet another example with MORE THAN THREE
>   blank spaces.      but the **boldface** *italics* underline [this word
>   was underlined in my google doc, but the current text area does not
>   have the underline font] formats were removed after the text was
>   replaced.         how do i keep these attributes ?

after running the script cap13a, the capitalization of the sentences was all correct as shown above, but all boldface, italics, underline attributes were removed; below is the transformed google doc:

> Capitalize sentences.  This is one example with ONE blank space after
>   the period.  Here is another example with TWO blank spaces after the
>   period.          This is yet another example with MORE THAN THREE
>   blank spaces.      But the boldface italics underline formats were
>   removed after the text was replaced.         How do i keep these
>   attributes ?

to see that the code did capitalize sentences correctly regardless of the number of blank spaces, see the above text as "code" below :

```
capitalize sentences.  this is one example with ONE blank space after the period.  here is another example with TWO blank spaces after the period.          this is yet another example with MORE THAN THREE blank spaces.      but the **boldface** _italics_ underline [this word was underlined in my google doc, but the current text area does not have the underline font] formats were removed after the text was replaced.         how do i keep these attributes ?
```

i obtained the following log:

> [15-10-24 13:51:35:055 EDT] regex1 -> (^|.)(s*)[a-z], regex2 ->
>   /(^|.)(\s*)[a-z]/ [15-10-24 13:51:35:128 EDT] doc -> Document
>   [15-10-24 13:51:35:129 EDT] body -> DocumentBodySection [15-10-24
>   13:51:35:130 EDT] atBody -> {FONT_SIZE=null, ITALIC=null,
>   PAGE_WIDTH=612.0, LINK_URL=null, UNDERLINE=null,
>   BACKGROUND_COLOR=null, MARGIN_BOTTOM=72.0, PAGE_HEIGHT=792.0,
>   MARGIN_RIGHT=72.0, STRIKETHROUGH=null, MARGIN_LEFT=72.0,
>   FOREGROUND_COLOR=null, BOLD=null, FONT_FAMILY=null, MARGIN_TOP=72.0}
>   [15-10-24 13:51:35:131 EDT] idBody -> [0, 232, 240, 241, 248, 249,
>   258] [15-10-24 13:51:35:132 EDT] foundElement -> RangeElement
>   [15-10-24 13:51:35:133 EDT] atFE -> {FONT_SIZE=null, ITALIC=null,
>   STRIKETHROUGH=null, FOREGROUND_COLOR=null, BOLD=null, LINK_URL=null,
>   UNDERLINE=null, FONT_FAMILY=null, BACKGROUND_COLOR=null} [15-10-24
>   13:51:35:635 EDT] body -> DocumentBodySection

it is noted that the attributes of the **original** document did not contain any boldface, italics, underline font, but only the margins !??  i don't know where such attributes were kept in the document, and how to access these attributes.

did i do something wrong in my code ?  i appreciate if someone could point out my errors.  thanks.

see also my post [google doc script, capitalize sentences without removing other attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33309227/google-doc-script-capitalize-sentences-without-removing-other-attributes) for the context of the above question.

Comment: The regex seems to be trimming the characters before the formatted words.

Comment: thanks, Rivero.  do you have a suggestion to change the regex so it would not trim the characters before the formatted words ?  note that if the regex were the culprit, it removed all formats uniformly, whether the format was boldface, italics, underline, or hyperlinks.  thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I'm having similar trouble too.  Sometimes Text.getAttributes(pos) just doesn't have the attributes that are actually visible on the screen.

Comment: The attributes on the Document as a whole only reflect things that are set for the whole document, so not surprising there's no BOLD set there.  And even for a Text there are different attributes at different positions.  It'll probably work better if instead of calling setText() to replace everything, you use foundText.deleteText(start,start+1) to delete the old letter and foundText.insertText(start, capitalLetter).  That should leave formatting on everything but the first letter in tact.  You may still have trouble with that first letter, though.